# How do I save a timestamp using json-server?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, json-server

I have been using json-server with a simple `db.json` to mock my REST API.

However, I have now have a requirement to save the current date on each POST in the back end.

I would like json-server to generate a timestamp on each POST and save it in the db.json so each time I do a GET request it would respond with the date that record was saved.

e.g. go from this:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "json-server",
      "author": "typicode"
    }
  ],
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "body": "some comment",
      "postId": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

To this:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "json-server",
      "author": "typicode"
    }
  ],
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "body": "some comment",
      "postId": 1,
      "timeSaved": "2020-09-17T09:15:27+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, this can be easily achieved with [@rnmkeshav/mock-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rnmkeshav/mock-api) package. It allows you to write everything in javascript with fine grained control of request and response. If you face any issue please raise a ticket on package's github repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json-server` as a module in combination with Express middleware: https://github.com/typicode/json-server#module.

They have an example to save createdAt for POST request:

```
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    req.body.createdAt = Date.now()
  }
  // Continue to JSON Server router
  next()
})
```

Or you can use my API server (based on json-server): https://github.com/robinhuy/fake-rest-api-nodejs